# Cannot rename resolv.conf file as root

Tags: debian, security, openvpn, resolv.conf, ownership

I am trying to activate NordVPN [CyberSec](https://nordvpn.com/blog/security-feature-cybersec/) by completing the following instructions in Debian 9. 
I should be able to do the changes as `root` and with `sudo` like described for Ubuntu in the thread [Should I edit my resolv.conf file to fix wrong DNS problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201603/should-i-edit-my-resolv-conf-file-to-fix-wrong-dns-problem) and in the thread [Linux: How do i edit resolv.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432026/linux-how-do-i-edit-resolv-conf) but I cannot.

> If you are using Linux or Mac OS X, please open the terminal and type
>   in: `su` You will be asked for your root password, please type it in and
>   press enter `rm -r /etc/resolv.conf nano /etc/resolv.conf` 
>   When the text
>   editor opens, please type in these lines:
>
> ```
> nameserver 103.86.99.99
> nameserver 103.86.96.96
> ```
>
> Now you have to close and save the file, you
>   can do that by clicking `Ctrl + X` and pressing `Y`. Then please
>   continue typing in the terminal:
>
> ```
> chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf 
> reboot now
> ```
>
> That is it. Your computer will reboot and everything should work
>   correctly. If you will ever need to change your DNS addresses, please
>   open the terminal and type in the following: su You will be asked for
>   your root password, please type it in and press enter
>
> ```
>  chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf 
>  nano /etc/resolv.conf
> ```
>
> Change DNS addresses, save and close the file.
>
> ```
>  chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
> ```

I do the first step as `su`/root but get the following. 
Trying to change the file `/etc/resolv.conf` content  there with `sudo`, I get `operation not permitted`.

```
root@masi:/etc# ls -la * | grep resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       89 Jan 22  2017 resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       89 Jul 25 17:10 resolv.conf~
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Jan 22  2017 resolv.conf.tmp
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1301 Nov 12  2015 update-resolv-conf

root@masi:/etc# sudo mv resolv.conf resolv.conf.tmp2
mv: cannot move 'resolv.conf' to 'resolv.conf.tmp2': Operation not permitted
```

OS: Debian 9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per your steps, you protected the file `/etc/resolv.conf` from being deleted/overwritten with chattr +i (immutable)

So, you won't be able to move it to another file without doing `sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` first.

From `man chattr`

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted
>   or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be
>   written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the
>   CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Comment: My internet stop working with the given nameservers. I need to add 8.8.4.4 there in the file. Do you understand why?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 They are their DNS servers, and they only work once their VPN is up; i.e. for their customers. While the answer is technically correct, the `chattr +i` only must be done (in a script), once the VPN is up.

Comment: Please, see my wiki answer for the explanation why you need the first line in the file. Can you agree?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 The question is devolving into VPN matters, I do advise to open other related questions.

Answer (score 0):

NordVPN's proposal about two nameservers did not work: internet does not work when VPN is not on - did not test it when it is on because I want that internet works when VPN is off too - maybe, this is the reason why you need `8.8.4.4` nameserver. 
You need instead

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 103.86.99.99
nameserver 103.86.96.96
```

I contacted the support to ask for the explanation about this.
I requested also for a tool to test that CyberSec feature works in my VPN connection.

Comment: This means you are using Google DNS in and out of VPN, and thus having DNS leaking outside of the VPN. Their DNS servers must be used while inside the VPN, and Google outside - in fact you may be using DNS in turns, more complicated, but you got the idea. Actually I have setup VPNs for use in our organization, and I intercept DNS requests, and it does not matter whichever DNS the client has configured. I am surprised both they do not do that, and also they do not provide clearer instructions.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I extended the thread here about the issue https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381771/16920

Answer (score 0):

```
Sudo chattr -a /etc/resolv.conf

Sudo lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
```

Remove file and make new file with only google dns ip.
It will work!

Comment: Also  -i  flag can achieve that file.